# What's the song used when previewing the next episode of Fairy Tail?

Tags: music, fairy-tail

At the end of each episode, there is a preview of the next episode. It also plays in the very beginning of episode 15 of the new *Fairy Tail* 2014, I think that makes it episode 190 in the total running.

What is the song that plays when they preview the next episode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The track that you're referring to is a bit unclear.

The pre-2014 preview music is different from the 2014+ preview music, and the music at the *very* beginning of 2014 episode 15 (the track *before* the theme song itself) is different from those two.

However, I notice that the track that plays immediately *after* the theme song in 2014 episode 15 is the same one as the one that plays during the 2014+ previews.

If this is the track that you are referring to, then the name of the song is

"**Fairy Tail Main Theme 2014 (FAIRY TAIL メインテーマ 2014)**"

(The Katakana as Romaji is "mein teimu" i.e. "main theme").

It is track 1 on disk 1 of the album "Fairy Tail Sound Collection" by Yasuharu Takanashi (the fifth original soundtrack for Fairy Tail if you don't count the movie soundtrack).

I believe that I have supplied enough information for you to look up the track. I am hesitant to link to a Youtube video because I have noticed that Fairy Tail OST videos get taken down due to copyright violations very quickly and frequently so I don't want to provide an invalid link.

Comment: This was indeed the track I was looking for, and for now I found a YouTube video that works (even though a lot of then have indeed been taken down) Thank you